# jquery load page to dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, webforms

I develop Intranet application with login via AD. In my application I need load web page from another application on same server and show this page in dialog.

```
$('#btnExample').click(function () {

var id = getCurrentId();
var url = 'http://SERVERNAME:81/Runtime/Forms/formDetail.aspx?SN=' + id;

                jQuery.support.cors = true;

                $('#pagePreview').load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                });

                $('#pagePreview').dialog(
                    {
                        draggable:false,
                        height: 768,
                        width: 1024,
                        modal: true,
                    });

                return false;
            });
```

The load function throw error: Access Denied.
Why? 
In my application is user logged by Active Directory and in the second app is logged too by AD...

Is any other way to resolve it? I need display this page in my site in a dilog.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second page is probably not on the same host as the first, so your request violates the "same origin policy".

As workaround, try an ajax request, load html into something, then populate the dialog with it. If the request is still denied make a local php script that makes a curl request to the specified page, and make an ajax request towards that script.

If it still fails... something is wrong.

Comment: On my test server running on IIS both app, but on different ports...
If i open the same url on new tab (or new windows) in browser it is OK...

Comment: Even if only the port is different the case is treated as a violation of the same origin policy. This is basically a limit, that does not allow scripts to access data outside their let's say "domain" for the lack of a better word. To work around you can do the curl request (that I specified in answer). It is annoying I know but... life sucks. Other solutions would be to use same domain and port for both apps, use an iframe in the dialog, or... since is an internal app, to disable the policy on all browsers that use the apps (tho I wouldn't suggest it).

Comment: Also you can check this for some (basic) details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript